# Why is tkinter geometry placement making my window appear in inconsistent locations on my screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter window I'd like to place in the middle of the screen, and am using Python 3 code like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window_width = 500
window_height = 400
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
horiz_centre = int((screen_width - window_width) / 2)
vert_centre = int((screen_height - window_height) / 2)
window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{horiz_centre}+{vert_centre}")

window.mainloop()
```

My window appears on the screen towards the top left, rather than centered as I'd like and expect from this code. My variables have the values I expect.

Running the same code multiple times does not guarantee the window will appear in the same location each time.

What's going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: What platform is this running on?  Sounds like the window manager is choosing to stagger window locations, rather than honoring the requested location.

Comment: Not reproducible on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me. It shows up in the middle of the screen every time I run the script - So that's the good news.

As far as why it's not working for you, I wonder if it could be the issue @jasonharper had stated in the comments. Otherwise I have had other issues that are similar with dual monitors and resolution settings that are worth a quick check.

**Give this a try:**

> 1.) Right-click your desktop and select "Display settings"

> 2.) Ensure your scale and layout are set to the recommended resolutions.

> 3.) Disconnect any additional monitors you may have connected.

Comment: Thank you! @jasonharper: I'm running on Windows 10, and with some searching have indeed found that I Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe) is running on my list of processes in the Task Manager. I haven't figured out if there is way to override the settings, but will be appeased that other users of the program I'm writing may not have this issue.

Comment: thank you @BMarshyyy--I am indeed working on multiple monitors. I tried your suggestions but the tkinter window placement remained unaffected, so it's probably the Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe) taking over, as you and jasonharper say.  Window Manager gaslighting me--relieved I guess the code is fine!

Comment: Darn - I was hoping it would be the easy simple answer for you. Best of luck, hopefully you get it figured out!